# how to make table with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hai.all..can you tell me how to make table in jquery?

i want using this plugin for showing all data which have been input from database..
i use `SELECT * FROM inspection_report` for showing data table inside process.php file...
how to combine with it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your creating from scratch you could do something like:

```
$('<table><tr>...</tr></table>').appendTo('body');
```

However I think you might be thinking of a data-grid. Check out this url for some good data-grid plugins: http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html

Comment: how about datatable?which better with jqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table in `HTML` and *enhance* it with jQuery.

**edit**: You can look at Ben Rowe's post in regards to jqGrid.

As for the PHP part of the question. There are [a few articles](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/PHP_with_MySQL.htm) on the web that cover the PHP and MYSQL interaction process nicely.